# How to pass initialization values for the member array in C++ template class arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, initialization

Let's say I have following template C++ class

```
template<uint32_t FILTER_ORDER, uint32_t BUFFER_LENGTH>
class Filter {
public:

    Filter() {}

private:
    float data_buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    const float filter_coefficients[FILTER_ORDER + 1];
};
```

I have been looking for a way how I can pass the coefficients of the filter i.e. individual items of the member array `filter_coefficients` at compile time. My goal is to have the ability to define filter object in following manner

```
Filter<3, 8, 1.0, 0.3678, 0.1353, 0.04978> filter;
```

where the last four non-type arguments of the template are the initialization values for the member array filter_coefficients. Does it exist a way how can I do that in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in C++20, before that `float` is not allowed as non-type template parameter.

```
template<uint32_t FILTER_ORDER, uint32_t BUFFER_LENGTH, float...values>
class Filter {
public:

    Filter() {}

private:
    float data_buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    const float filter_coefficients[FILTER_ORDER + 1]{values...};
};
```

But this embeds the values into the type, is that really what you want? It will prevent storing arrays of these objects because they now have different types.

I would recommend just using `constexpr` constructor. Why do you need them to be compile-time anyway?

C++14 variant with `constexpr` constructor:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <array>

template<std::uint32_t FILTER_ORDER, std::uint32_t BUFFER_LENGTH>
class Filter {
public:

    Filter() {}

    template<typename...Floats,typename=decltype(std::array<float,FILTER_ORDER+1>{std::declval<Floats>()...})>
    constexpr Filter(Floats...floats):filter_coefficients{floats...}{}
    
private:
    // Consider using `std::array` here too.
    float data_buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    const float filter_coefficients[FILTER_ORDER + 1];
};

int main(){
    Filter<3, 4> filter{1.0f,2.0f,3.0f,1.0f};
}
```

There is basic type check to ensure the elements are `float`s, otherwise this variadic template can shadow some other constructors.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. Originally I haven't realize the problem with different types you have mentioned. So it would be really better to avoid it. Unfortunately I am not sure that I understand the idea with the constexpr constructor. May I ask you for an example?

Comment: @ProfessorJimatura Sure, give me a second.

Comment: @ProfessorJimatura Took more than a second, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example. It uses very advanced C++ constructs from my point of view. I need to at first study the variadic templates before I understand how does it work. Let me have a question. Does it work also for ordinary array instead of the std::array?

Comment: @ProfessorJimatura Yes, the example works with ordinary array, `std::array` is just used to SFINAE restrict the `Floats` arguments. Because a variadic constructor tends to shadow other constructors unless it is restricted and we only want `Floats` to really be `float`